# Flask-classy: how to make a link for `delete` request

Tags: python-2.7, flask, jinja2

I am using `flask-classy` to have my views restful style. Following is some method with `delete` request:

```
class FooView(FlaskView):
  @route('/<int:id>/', endpoint='foo.delete', methods=['DELETE'])
  def bar(self, id):
    return 'this is delete method'
```

When this method works fine when i'm testing it with `curl -X DELETE localhost:2000/foo/1/` or with jquery ajax request. However, i do not know how to make a link in jinja2 for the method. Any idea how can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify an HTTP method for anchor tags. They all result in `GET` requests. If you want to support a method other than `GET`, such as `DELETE` or `POST`, you need to use JavaScript, which you said you already have working.